# GoogleMap current location search issue

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-permissions

I have created an app which uses Google Map and I have used both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION AND ACESS_FINE_LOCATION permission as you can see in the image. My question is that to know the current location I have to use my wifi but shouldn't it give me my location by searching cell towers if wifi isn't available [image]

Comment: yes it will, maybe you should elaborate on what the problem is. What you posted does not tell us much of anything

Comment: problem is like if wifi is off then it display a default map(not current location), but if I want to know my current location on map then I have only one option to switch on wifi otherwise it just diaplay's a default map

Comment: does your device have a GPS chip? is this a wifi only device? it can take some time to lock onto the satellites

Comment: yes,ok then I will try again and see if it responds after sometime.